# Example of $\overline{A}\cap\overline{D} \neq \overline{A\cap D}$

Tags: general-topology

I want to find sets $A, D \subset \mathbb{R}$ (with the topology induced by the usual distance in $\mathbb{R}$) so that the following sets are different:
$$\overline{A}\cap D \quad ; \quad A \cap \overline{D} \quad; \quad \overline{A}\cap\overline{D} \quad ; \quad \overline{A\cap D}$$
I have tried several sets and I am unable to find a pair of sets that do right by  $\overline{A}\cap\overline{D} \neq \overline{A\cap D}$. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: $A=(0,1),D=(1,2)$.

Comment: Or $A=$ rationals, $D=$ irrationals.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy your example doesn't work since $A \cap \overline{D} = \overline{A} \cap D$

Comment: My example is for the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing these kind of closure, intersection questions, you can try to play around with accumulation points. Consider the sets:

$$ A = (0, 1) \cup \{ 2 \} $$
$$ B = \{ 1 \} \cup (2, 4) $$

We can check that
$$ \bar{A} \cap B = 1, \quad
A \cap \bar {B} = 2, \quad
\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = 1, 2, \quad
\overline{A \cap B} = \emptyset $$

Some intuition: First, lets try $A$ and $B$ disjoint. Then $A \cap B = \emptyset$, and we focus on ensuring the 3 other sets are non empty.
Next, taking closure allows you to add an extra point. So you want the closure of $A$ to gain you an extra point, say $1$. Similarly, you want the closure of $B$ to gain you an extra point, say $2$. Then a bit of trial and error gives you a valid example.

Answer (score 2):

Take any two disjoint dense sets in $\mathbb R$. For example, the set of all rational numbers and the set of all irrational numbers. Then the four sets become $D, A, \mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$.